# PHP: array search when array doesn't start on zero

Tags: php, arrays, key

I'm trying to find a key in an array that doesn't start with zero.

This is my not so elegant solution:

```
private $imagetypes = [
    1 => [
        'name' => 'banner_big',
        'path' => 'campaigns/big/'
    ],
    2 => [
        'name' => 'banner_small',
        'path' => 'campaigns/small/'
    ],
// ...
```

If i use `$key = array_search('banner_big', array_column($this->imagetypes, 'name'));` the result is `0`

I came up with this solution but I feel like I needlessly complicated the code:

```
 /**
 * @param string $name
 * @return int
 */
public function getImagetypeFromName($name)
{
    $keys = array_keys($this->imagetypes);
    $key = array_search($name, array_column($this->imagetypes, 'name'));
    if ($key !== false && array_key_exists($key, $keys)) {
        return $keys[$key];
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Is there a better solution then this.

I can't change the keys in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just save indexes

```
$key = array_search('banner_big',
                     array_combine(array_keys($imagetypes),
                                    array_column($imagetypes, 'name')));
```

**[demo on eval.in](https://eval.in/792330)**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `array_column` will return a new array (without the existing indexes)

So in your example.

```
$key = array_search('banner_big', array_column($this->imagetypes, 'name'));

var_dump($key);

//$key is 0 as 0 is the key for the first element in the array returned by array_column.
```

You can mitigate against this by creating a new array with the existing keys.

Answer (score 0):

That's  because `array_column()`  generates another  array (starting  at
index zero), as you may have imagined. An idea to solve this would be to
transform the  array with  `array_map()`, reducing it  to key  and image
name (which  is what you're searching  for). The keys will  be the same,
and this can be achieved with a simple callback:

```
function($e) {
    return $e['name'];
}
```

So, a full implementation for your case:

```
public function
getImagetypeFromName($name)
{
    $key = array_search($name, array_map(function($e) {
        return $e['name'];
    }, $this->imagetypes));

    return $key ?: -1;
}
```